# Recovering presenters for the ViewPager fragments (MVP)

Tags: android, mvp, android-mvp

I'm trying to refactor an existing application to use the MVP architecture. One of the activities has a `ViewPager` with three fragments. Each fragment is linked with a presenter. To be precise - each presenter, when created, is given a `View` to work with, i.e. a `Fragment`. For now, I'm creating these presenters inside the `ViewPager`'s adapter - specifically in the `getItem(int position)` method.

```
Fragment fragment = FirstFragment.newInstance();
FirstPresenter presenter = new FirstPresenter(repo, (FirstContract.View) fragment, projectId, userId);
```

The problem I'm facing is if the process is killed and then restarted, `ViewPager` has its own lifecycle and therefore `getItem` is not called again - the fragments are recreated automagically with no presenters.

Is there a known solution to this problem?

Comment: I think in android the view creates the Presenter, just because of the lifecycles of the activity/fragment. So you should remove the initialisation from the viewpager to the fragment itself

Comment: so manage the lifecycle of the presenters alongwith the fragment lifecycles

Comment: Makes sense... However I would like to see if there are other ways around this, to decouple the presenter initialisation from the fragment

Answer (score 4):

As there's still no ideal answer to this question, I thought it might be good to share my interim solution.

As I've mentioned in one of the comments, the goal here is to recover `ViewPager` from process kill and ideally keep the Presenter initialisation decoupled from the View. For now, my solution is to override `restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader)` inside the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, inspect the state `Parcelable` similar to the actual implementation of the `restoreState` method, then for each fragment of a certain class, I can initialise a presenter and assign it a view.

```
@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    if (state != null) {
        Bundle bundle = (Bundle)state;
        bundle.setClassLoader(loader);
        Iterable<String> keys = bundle.keySet();
        for (String key: keys) {
            if (key.startsWith("f")) {
                Fragment f = mFragmentManager.getFragment(bundle, key);
                if (f != null) {
                    if (f instanceof FirstFragment) {
                       new FirstPresenter(repo, (FirstContract.View) f, projectId, userId);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, ".restoreState() - bad fragment at key " + key);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    super.restoreState(state, loader);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments - **Presenter** must be attached (and detached) in Activity/Fragment lifecycle methods. Not in external classes because only **View** can manage to attach-detach **Presenter** at appropriate time. *But* it's a good practice to *initilize* **Presenter** in separate class (or dependency injection framework) to decouple it from **View**.

Comment: Fair point. The problem still exists - how do I pass the initialised Presenter to the View when we're talking about a ViewPager. Cause I do want them to be decoupled and I don't like the idea of initialising a presenter inside a view. Also I kinda like the idea of the presenter being assigned a view, as specified in https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture

Answer (score 0):

The suggested answer didn't work for me since `mFragmentManager` is a private member of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. No idea how it worked for vkislicins. Instead, I just called got the parent class to do `restoreState` then grabbed the fragments with 'instantiateItem'. For example:

```
@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    // this will load all the fragments again
    super.restoreState(state, loader);

    // since the fragments are now loaded, instantiate can be used because it just returns them
    MyFragmentClass tab1 = (MyFragmentClass) instantiateItem(null, 0);
    tab1Presenter.setView(tab1);
    tab1.setPresenter(tab1Presenter);

    // then just do the same for the other fragments
    ...
}
```

Feels a bit hacky, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, my solution includes `FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks`, which is a

> Callback interface for listening to fragment state changes that happen within a given FragmentManager

and sticks with the separation of concerns, in a way that's shown in the [Android Architecture Blueprints](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture), I'd say.

- `Activity` creates `Presenter`, passing along `View`/ `Fragment`, so that
- `Presenter` knows its `View` and furthermore sets itself its `Presenter`

---

In `Activity`'s `onCreate` I register a `FragmentLifecycleCallbacks` listener by calling this

```
private void registerFragmentsLifecycleListener() {

    // All registered callbacks will be automatically unregistered when
    // this FragmentManager is destroyed.
    getSupportFragmentManager.registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(
        new FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {

            // Called after the fragment has returned from its onActivityCreated
            @Override
            public void onFragmentActivityCreated(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f,
                                                  Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                createPresenter(f);
            }
        }, false); // true to register callback for all child FragmentManagers
}
```

The listener gets notified after the `Fragment` has returned from its `onActivityCreated` to make sure, that only for each **new** `Fragment` instance added by the `ViewPager` a new `Presenter` will be created. The fragment could get attached/detached, its view could be created/destroyed a couple of times, nothing needed to be done, still got its `Presenter`.

Because in case of recreation (e.g. by rotation) the `Fragment`s' `onCreate` is called before the `Activity`s one (where the `FragmentLifecycleCallbacks` listener is registered!), the listener couldn't implement `onFragmentCreated`, it has to be `onFragmentActivityCreated`.

For the given new `Fragment` instance we can then determine which `Presenter` is needed:

```
private void createPresenter(Fragment fragment) {

    if (fragment instanceof WhateverContract.View) {

        WhateverContract.Presenter whateverPresenter =
            new WhateverPresenter((WhateverContract.View) fragment);

    } else if (...){}
}
```

The `Presenter` connects with its `View`/`Fragment` in the constructor

```
private final WhateverContract.View mView;

public WhateverPresenter(@NonNull WhateverContract.View view) {

    mView = checkNotNull(view, "view cannot be null!");
    mView.setPresenter(this);
}
```

and can then be started in the `Fragment`s `onResume`.

---

If there's something wrong or to improve, please let me know :)